# find transition matrix

Tags: matrices

Layman question here.

I have a square matrix, $Z_1$ as shown below.  It is found by inverting a matrix named $Y_1$.  The $x$ values in row 4 and col 4 may be zero or non-zero and the off-diagonals are equal (e.g. the 1,4 element equals the 4,1 element). The 4,4 and at least one of the off-diagonals will be non-zero.

[image]

There is a second square matrix, $Z_2$ as shown below.  It is found by inverting another matrix named $Y_2$.

[image]

Is there a way to calculate a transition matrix that I can use somehow with $Y_1$ to find $Y_2$ directly?  The submatrix in green will be the same in both $Z_1$ and $Z_2$.

I'm playing around with the Ward Equivalent method from [this 1949 paper](https://ieeexplore-ieee-org.proxy.lib.utc.edu/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5059947) and am wondering if there's a better way.

**EDIT - added example with real values.**  The $Z_2$ matrix will be the submatrix in green below.

[image]

thanks,
russ

Comment: Do you mean to say that the matrix Z is symmetric? What do you mean by a transition matrix? Is the Z2 matrix just a submatrix of Z1?

Comment: Yes @Bcpicao, all the matrices here are symmetric.  I want a matrix (I called it a transition matrix) that when used somehow with Y1 would produce Y2.  Yes, Z2 is sub matrix of Z1.  But, I want to find Y2 from Y1 without going through inverting Z

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform $\mathbf{Z_1}\ (4\times 4)$  into $\mathbf{Z_2}\ (3\times 3)$ with a transition matrix $\mathbf A$, it'll have to be with this operation for sure:
$$\mathbf{Z_2}=\mathbf{AZ_1A}^\top,$$
where $\mathbf A$ needs to be $(3\times 4)$ because
$$(m,n)\times(4,4)\times(n,m)=(3,3)\iff (n,m)=(3,4)$$
Notice if not that there's no simpler operation that satisfies that since for $\mathbf{Z_2=AZ_1}$
$$(n,m)\times(4,4)=(3,3)\iff \nexists (n,m)$$
Therefore, expressed in terms of $\mathbf{Y_1}$ and $\mathbf{Y_2}$ (although cheating a bit) this'd be
$$\mathbf{Z_2}=\mathbf{AZ_1A}^\top\iff(\mathbf{Y_2})^{-1}=\mathbf{A(Y_1)^{-1}A}^\top\iff\mathbf{Y_2}=(\mathbf{A(Y_1)^{-1}A}^\top)^{-1},$$
for known $\mathbf A$ and $\mathbf{Y_1}$.

A particular example satisfying $\mathbf{Z_2}=\mathbf{AZ_1A}^\top$ would be
$$\mathbf A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 &  &  & |\ 0\\
 \ & \mathbf{I_{3\times 3}} &  & |\ 0\\
 &  &  & |\ 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you.  I edited my post to show real values.  Can you show how to find A for that case?